# react-native Image Cache never expires for the same uri

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

react-native Image Cache never expires for the same uri.
  Even the image from the same uri is changed,
  and if the uri do not change the view will not render.
  i read some writings， they said add ?random=*** to the uri. 
  is there anotherway?

Comment: They add `?random=***` to change the uri

Comment: @Danh i know that   i thought whether or not has a better way :)

Comment: from what I know, change uri is the only way

Comment: @Danh thank you, i will use this method